# Error while building code in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

Can anybody help me with this, I'm able to commit changes from both Git Bash and Android Studio initially, but as soon as I test the app in Android Studio, i.e., build it. After that I'm unable to commit and push the changes anymore and get this error:

`PS C:\Users\xenon\StudioProjects\Anki-Android> ./gradlew jacocoUnitTestReport`

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Anki-Android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.2.2
         project : > com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:8.2.2
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.6' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.6')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.6')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.6')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.6')

* Try:
> Review the variant matching algorithm at https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/variant_attributes.html#sec:abm_algorithm.
> No matching variant errors are explained in more detail at https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/variant_model.html#sub:variant-no-match.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
```

Comment: Got the solution , had to download jdk from the oracle website before that i just had a simple java 8 version installed . Ty myself :))